# Define unique constraint for PostgreSQL deployment

Tags: postgresql, django-models, heroku-postgres

I am trying to deploy to Heroku and converting from sqlite3 to postgres.

A given Showtime refers to a Film and a Venue.

I think I'm just missing some kind of declaration for the model setup that designates the foreign key fields as unique.

When I run make migrations I get the following error. T

```
  Applying venues.0018_auto_20170824_1907...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "venues_venue"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_c
ommand_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_for
wards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 216, in databas
e_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 515, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 112, in _alter_fi
eld
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 773, in _alter_field
    self.execute(self._create_fk_sql(model, new_field, "_fk_%(to_table)s_%(to_column)s"))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "venues_venue"



class Venue(models.Model):
name            = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False)
venue_id        = models.SmallIntegerField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)

class Film(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    film_id         = models.SmallIntegerField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)

class Showtime(models.Model):
showtime_id     = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
venue_id        = models.ForeignKey(Venue, to_field="venue_id", db_column="venue_id")
film_id         = models.ForeignKey(Film, to_field="film_id", db_column="film_id")
```

Comment: Probably not the issue, but why do make your life so difficult with all these superfluous manual id fields (that you do not even use as pk fields) and misnomered foreign keys? You will access a `Venue` instance via `showtime.venue_id` and its id via `showtime.venue_id_id`!

Comment: Where were you when I spend two days trying to figure out `showtime.venue_id_id` because of the foreign key? I appreciate your comment, however, you didn't answer the question directly.